# Simplifying - Integration by Parts Functions

Tags: calculus, integration

I tried to use integration-by-parts for this integral and ended up getting a long group of fractions:
$$
\int e^{5x}\sin(6x) dx
 = \frac{1}{5} {e^{5x}\sin (6x)}
 - \frac{6}{25}{e^{5x}\cos(6x)}
 + \frac{36}{25} \int e^{5x} \sin(6x) \, dx
$$ how would I solve to for the variable to get $\int e^{5x}\sin(6x) \, dx$ ? I am able to use $u$-substitution but I end up getting a group of large fractions and am not sure how to isolate the answer properly.

Comment: Might be easier to write $\sin 6x = { 1\over 2i} (e^{6ix}-{e^{-6ix}})$?

Comment: @copper.hat OP may not know complex analysis...

Comment: @gt6989b: Hence my comment?

Comment: @copper.hat sorry typo, OP may not know complex analysis, so complex exponents for him may be overkill... but they make the problem so much more easily doable :)

Comment: Whenever you have $e^{ax}\sin(bx)$ or $e^{ax}\cos(bx)$ as the integrand, you want to collect the integral on one side then divide by the coefficient (since the integral repeats on the other side). Just bring $\dfrac{36}{25}\displaystyle\int e^{5x}\sin(6x)\mathrm dx$ to the other side and divide both sides by $-\dfrac{11}{25}$.

Answer (score 5):

From your expression, if $I = \int e^{5x}\sin(6x) dx$, your equation reads
$$
I = \frac{e^{5x}\sin (6x)}{5}
 - \frac{e^{5x}6\cos(6x)}{25}
 + \frac{36}{25} I,
$$
just solve for $I$.

Answer (score 2):

(Always remember the integral you start with so you can solve for it if you get it again later.  More generally, remember all the integrals you generate along the way so you can recognize a cycle, solve for the cycle, then use that to finish evaluating the integral.)

(It really does help to give the starting integral a name.  Humans are much better at remembering things by name.)

Let $I = \int \mathrm{e}^{5x} \sin(6x) \,\mathrm{d}x$.  Then, \begin{align*}
&\qquad\qquad \begin{bmatrix} 
u = \sin(6x), & \mathrm{d}v = \mathrm{e}^{5x} \,\mathrm{d}x \\
\mathrm{d}u = 6 \cos(6x) \,\mathrm{d}x, & v = \frac{1}{5} \mathrm{e}^{5x}
\end{bmatrix}  \\
I &= \frac{1}{5} \mathrm{e}^{5x} \sin(6x) - \frac{6}{5}\int \mathrm{e}^{5x} \cos(6x)  \\
&\qquad\qquad \begin{bmatrix} 
u = \cos(6x), & \mathrm{d}v = \mathrm{e}^{5x} \,\mathrm{d}x \\
\mathrm{d}u = -6 \sin(6x) \,\mathrm{d}x, & v = \frac{1}{5} \mathrm{e}^{5x}
\end{bmatrix}  \\
&= \frac{1}{5} \mathrm{e}^{5x} \sin(6x) - \frac{6}{5} \left( \frac{1}{5}\mathrm{e}^{5x}\cos(6x) - \frac{-6}{5}\int \mathrm{e}^{5x} \sin(6x) \,\mathrm{d}x \right)  \\
&= \frac{1}{5} \mathrm{e}^{5x} \sin(6x) - \frac{6}{5} \left( \frac{1}{5}\mathrm{e}^{5x}\cos(6x) - \frac{-6}{5}I \right)  \\
&= \frac{1}{5} \mathrm{e}^{5x} \sin(6x) - \frac{6}{25}\mathrm{e}^{5x}\cos(6x) - \frac{36}{25}I  \text{.}
\end{align*}
So, \begin{align*}
\frac{25}{25} I &= \frac{1}{5} \mathrm{e}^{5x} \sin(6x) - \frac{6}{25}\mathrm{e}^{5x}\cos(6x) - \frac{36}{25}I  \text{,}  \\
\frac{25}{25} I + \frac{36}{25}I &= \frac{1}{5} \mathrm{e}^{5x} \sin(6x) - \frac{6}{25}\mathrm{e}^{5x}\cos(6x)  \text{,}  \\
\frac{61}{25}I &= \frac{1}{5} \mathrm{e}^{5x} \sin(6x) - \frac{6}{25}\mathrm{e}^{5x}\cos(6x)  \text{, and }  \\
I &= \frac{5}{61} \mathrm{e}^{5x} \sin(6x) - \frac{6}{61}\mathrm{e}^{5x}\cos(6x)  \text{.}
\end{align*}